# java hashmap return key and value for specific key entered

Tags: java, search, hashmap

I am using hashmaps and am running into an issue. for my program, I am developing an address book where each person has a first and last name and a corresponding address. My hashmap, therefore, has a person object as its key and an address as its value. I am trying to iterate through my hashmap and print the key and value of a specified person, here is my code so far:

```
public class AddressBook {
    private Map<Person, Address> contacts = new ConcurrentHashMap<Person, Address>();

    public void addContact(Person p, Address a) {
        this.contacts.put(p, a);
    }

    public void removeContact(Person p) {
        this.contacts.remove(p);
    }

    public boolean hasContact(Person p) {
        return this.contacts.containsKey(p);
    }

    public void listAllContacts(){
        for (Map.Entry<Person,Address> entry : contacts.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
}
    }

    public void listContact(Person p){
        for (int i=0;i<contacts.size();i++) {

        }
    }
}
```

for example, if I had a person Charles in the hashmap how could I search it and print charles key and value data. in my list all contacts method I print all the keys and values but i need to do it for a specific key. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Maps wouldn't be nearly as useful without [a handy way to get the value from a key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: I understand how to get the value from the key, I am asking how to print the key and the value for a specific key

Comment: Since the map is not keyed by single name, you'd have to scan the entire map and find all entries where the persons name is `Charles`. Perhaps you should re-think what you want to lookup by, and whether there can be more than one entry by that, e.g. two or more people named `Charles`, or some with first name `Charles` and others with last name `Charles`.

Comment: I'm starting to think I have worded this rather badly. Okay, so say a Person object p1 is the key and that object p1 has an address value. is there a way to print the objects p1 key and its value like .getKey and .getValue but for the one object

Comment: Before taking this any further, are you sure `Person` makes a good key? How did you implement `equals` and `hashCode`? Also, it has to be immutable. Isn't there a simpler key you can use (some `personId` maybe)?

Comment: As for your original question, it looks like you want to do `println(p + " : " +contacts.get(p))`

Comment: You might want to use the `lastName` of the person as the key and then store all values in a `List<Person>`.  You would then use another method to find the particular person you require.

Comment: Hi, Thilo. I havent actually implemented equals or hashcode. Also, I honestly don't know how I overlooked that I can simply toString() person p to get the key data, *Facepalm* I considered person to be a good key as it holds the persons name and directly corrolates to an address for that person, I didnt think having the first and last name in the Address class would be a good idea

Comment: Why would you use a Map to associate an Address with a Person, when you can simply make the address a field of the `Person` class?

Comment: Hi, Erwin. Yeah, I have definitely overcomplicated this task with using a hashmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to print the Key and values of a Person by simply using the toString method to print the key `System.out.println(p.toString() + contacts.get(p));` and the `get()` method to retrieve the value to that key